# Is it possible to embed JDK and other requirements into runnable jar?

Tags: java, eclipse

Two days ago I got close to finishing a java program that wrote, I wanted to let some friends play with it for a bit to find flaws etc. I created a runnable jar trough Eclipse and then I used Launch4j to transform the runnable jar into a .exe
It worked perfectly fine on my pc, but any other user couldn't open it. After a while I discovered that when people would install java JDK, it worked for about 40%, but this atleast pushed me in the direction of what the flaw is. Is there a way to (automaticly?) embed everything in the jar that my program is in need of? Or is there a way to determine what exactly it all is that people need for the .exe to run and what they are missing by running some pre-checks that can re-direct them to links where they can download this? I can't seem to find much on this subject, so I probably made a mis assumption somewhere, any help/clearance is appreciated!

Comment: Try `jpackage` which comes with newer java versions. A tutorial on how to use it: https://www.baeldung.com/java14-jpackage

Comment: Literally no ... since you need a JDK (actually a JRE, but we are splitting hairs) to load and run a JAR.  But you can create (platform specific) binary. See the first answer.

Comment: @StephenC so installing the latest JRE should be enough to cover it all or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes.  Assuming that you have *tested* your application with the *latest* JRE or JDK.  But be aware that Oracle and many other Java vendors stopped distributing JREs after Java 8.  So if you are providing installation instructions to users, they need to be nuanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a new tool called [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html), which should do what you want.

Also see the [User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jpackage/packaging-overview.html).

Comment: And [*jlink*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282), to assemble and optimize a set of modules and their dependencies into a custom run-time image.

Comment: Thanks, this is a cool solution where I had no knowledge of.